# NDK debugging with r9 works on W7/64 but gives me issues in XP

Tags: android-ndk, gdbserver, ndk-gdb

I've recently loaded the new Android dev tools, SDK 20130717 and NDK r9.

Up to now I had the previous versions, working and debugging from within Eclipse just fine on both of my systems, a XP and a W7/64.

Now, the W7/64 with the new tools does work and debug my apps ok after the new tools installation and the required path environment changes.

It works ok when I select the "Debug As" + "Android Native Application".

Yet the XP, although they have the exact configuration in terms of folders/cygwin etc, after the new tools installed and the necessary path env changed, it looks that it can't start the ndk-dbg and it;s stuck waiting in definitively at "Launching MyApp(1): (100%)".
That happens after I select the "Debug As" + "Android Native Application".

Any hints on what might be the cause of it? or
is there any known issue on XP and r9 debugging that I miss?

thanks,
Christos

*edit

Tried to start manually the ndk-gdb and this is what I get, any hints are welcome

> Blockquote
>
> $ ndk-gdb --start --verbose --force
>
> Android NDK installation path: /cygdrive/e/android-ndk-r9
>
> Using default adb command: /cygdrive/e/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130717/sdk/platform-tools/adb
>
> ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
>
> Using ADB flags:
>
> Using JDB command: /cygdrive/e/Android/Java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/jdb
>
> Using auto-detected project path: .
>
> Found package name: myndkpackage
>
> ABIs targetted by application: armeabi-v7a
>
> Device API Level: 17
>
> Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
>
> Compatible device ABI: armeabi-v7a
>
> Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
>
> Using toolchain prefix: /cygdrive/e/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>
> Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a
>
> Found debuggable flag: true
>
> Found device gdbserver: /data/data/myndkpackage/lib/gdbserver
>
> Found data directory: '/data/data/myndkpackage'
>
> Found first launchable activity: myndkpackage.MainActivity
>
> Launching activity: myndkpackage/myndkpackage.MainActivity
>
> COMMAND: adb_cmd shell am start -D -n myndkpackage/myndkpackage.MainActivity
>
> Starting: Intent { cmp=myndkpackage/.MainActivity }
>
> COMMAND: adb_cmd shell sleep 2
>
> Found running PID: 2787
>
> Killing existing debugging session
>
> COMMAND: adb_cmd shell kill -9 2753
>
> Launched gdbserver succesfully.
>
> Setup network redirection
>
> COMMAND: adb_cmd shell run-as myndkpackage lib/gdbserver +debug-socket --attach 2787
>
> COMMAND: adb_cmd forward tcp:5039 localfilesystem:/data/data/myndkpackage/debug-socket
>
> Attached; pid = 2787
>
> Listening on Unix socket debug-socket
>
> COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/bin/app_process obj/local/armeabi-v7a/app_process
>
> 599 KB/s (9588 bytes in 0.015s)
>
> Pulled app_process from device/emulator.
>
> COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/bin/linker obj/local/armeabi-v7a/linker
>
> 658 KB/s (63244 bytes in 0.093s)
>
> Pulled linker from device/emulator.
>
> COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/lib/libc.so obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libc.so
>
> 744 KB/s (297608 bytes in 0.390s)
>
> Pulled libc.so from device/emulator.
>
> Setup JDB connection
>
> COMMAND: adb_cmd forward tcp:65534 jdwp:2787
>
> java.io.IOException: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed
>
> at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.handshake(SocketTransportService.java:136)
>
> at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.attach(SocketTransportService.java:232)
>
> at com.sun.tools.jdi.GenericAttachingConnector.attach(GenericAttachingConnector.java:116)
>
> at com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketAttachingConnector.attach(SocketAttachingConnector.java:90)
>
> at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.attachTarget(VMConnection.java:519)
>
> at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.open(VMConnection.java:328)
>
> at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Env.init(Env.java:63)
>
> at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.TTY.main(TTY.java:1066)
>
> Fatal error:
>
> Unable to attach to target VM.
>
> /cygdrive/e/android-ndk-r9/ndk-gdb: line 742:  4636 Segmentation fault      $GDBCLIENT -x `native_path $GDBSETUP`
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 4):

Ok,

From what I understand, its a problem in the new r9 release, specifically in the file named

android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb

This executable gives the segmentation fault.

So it looks that in the distro it has not been generated correctly from the start, from the android devs themselves who uploaded it on the main android site.

I tried and re-downloaded the r9 distribution and re-installed, yet the same thing happens so it was not something accidental eg a bad unzip.

I tried the older r8e same file and it does not give the segmentation fault, it works ok.

So, I did something to get a proof of concept of what I say and took the previous version file (from r8e) and overwrite the new r9 file, then tried again to run the failing ndk-dbg and..

..IT WORKS..

Now I have a new r9 NDK but with one file from the r8e, the old arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe and everything works just fine!

So I guess the android devs have to re-do the compilation of the

-> android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe

tool, properly this time.

At least I hope someone will find this useful and avoid the frustration that I had all this time.

Christos

Comment: solved the segmentation problem for me. Thanks for taking the time to post.

Comment: The downgrade also helped me! Thanx! I'm going to try upgrading to r9 and replacing the one file as you suggested. Did you ever file a bug report on the issue?

Comment: they didn't fix it yet; same problem in r10d

Answer (score 3):

[This is the bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58975) that was opened on the Android NDK. A work-around is to use the `arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe` from Android NDK r8e (as described in Christos' answer), or to download a fixed file from http://code.google.com/p/mingw-and-ndk/downloads/detail?name=arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, the problem with gdb appears to be fixed in r9b of the NDK.

https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

> Fixed a problem with Windows 32-bit *-gdb.exe executables failing to
>   launch. ([Issue 58975](http://b.android.com/58975))