# ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI returns 2 lines on Windows

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

I can't debug android ndk app on Windows.
It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047348/unknown-application-abi-while-debug-as-native-application) it is a new line problem on Windows

```
c:\Android\android-ndk-r9c\samples\hello-jni>..\..\ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI
all

c:\Android\android-ndk-r9c\samples\hello-jni>
```

On Linux it is

```
hello-jni$ ../../ndk-build DUMP_APP_ABI
all
hello-jni$
```

There is no line after `all` on Linux

I use unmodified `hello-jni` from `android-ndk-r9c`

I also compared size of every unzipped file and they are original. It is clean unmodified NDK from Google.
It is able to compile and do JavaDebug but not NativeDebug. (on Windows)

My questions is: What I am doing wrong? Does someone can confirm that unmodifed `Android NDK r9c` (latest today) is able to do native debugging with Eclipse+NDKPlugin.

**PS**
I forgot to mention that when I do Native Debug I get

```
[2013-11-18 14:38:50 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI: 
[2013-11-18 14:38:50 - HelloJni] 
[2013-11-18 14:38:50 - HelloJni] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

Just like in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047348/unknown-application-abi-while-debug-as-native-application/20050696)

Comment: is it 32-bit or 64-bit NDK?

Comment: Good catch! I have just checked: it's the `prebuilt/windows/bin/make.exe` in both 32 and 64 bit versions of **NDK r9c**.

Comment: Thank You! 64 bit. You answered my question. Please add answer and I will mark it as answered. Thanks again.

Comment: You mean, 32 bit version works? Oh, great!

Comment: No. I have 64bit NDK on both Windows and Linux. Linux works and Windows don't.  I am downloading 32 bit NDK now.

Comment: I downloaded r9c 32bit and I get same error. It is on both 32 and 64 bit NDK on Windows.

Comment: Apparently, some people succeeded with this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910859/ndk-debugging-with-r9-works-on-w7-64-but-gives-me-issues-in-xp. The key difference may be around cygwin installation.

Comment: The bug mentioned there is different. There is no `Unknown Application ABI:` that I forgot to mention in my question. That in that post with dbg 32 bit was fixed in `r9b`.

Comment: Ha! That's the point: your question was: "is it possible to receive valid DUMP_APP_ABI on Windows in NDR r9?". Their link proves that it is possible.

Comment: That thread made me think it is only bug in NDK on Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047348/unknown-application-abi-while-debug-as-native-application I was wrong it has other bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that the the issue is which `make` is used by `ndk-gdb`. See *[ndk-gdb on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020245/ndk-gdb-on-windows)*: when cygwin's `make` is used, all well; if cygwin `make` is not installed, `ndk-gdb` fails. Here is the summary from *[Debugging Android NDK, Under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307638/192373)*:

1. add `android:debuggable="true"` flag to `<application` tag in **AndroidManifest.xml**
2. in **cmd** (windows' command prompt): invoke `ndk-build` with `NDK_DEBUG=1`
3. in **cygwin** bash: run `ndk-gdb`